# pkg_resources not found while installing java on Mac

Tags: python, homebrew, homebrew-cask

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

My `PYTHONPATH` contains `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, the site-packages folder indeed contains the `pkg_resources` folder. I tried everything and have spent hours searching stack overflow. I even reinstalled python and setuptools, but nothing seems to work.

The command I am using to install Java - `brew cask install java`

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was so lost trying to install it with `brew`, that I forgot that I could download the dmg file from the Oracle website and install it. I still can't figure out the issue with `pkg_resources` though.